# zoom image on mouse hover in css

Tags: html, css, mouseover, zooming

I don't understand what is happening with my code. Everything works fine but, the main problem is that the next image is shifting to the next line. I don't want to shift the image to next line. Is there any solution so that the image remain in that line. I don't want to use any `<table>` tag.
Please help...!

Here's my code:

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.imz {
    top: 50%;
    left: 100%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);    /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);     /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);      /* Opera */
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
.emz {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
.emz img {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;    /* Firefox */
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;      /* IE 9 */
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;     /* Opera */
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.emz:hover img {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.05); /* Safari and Chrome */
    -moz-transform:scale(1.05);    /* Firefox */
    -ms-transform:scale(1.05);     /* IE 9 */
    -o-transform:scale(1.05);      /* Opera */
     transform:scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div class="imz">
    <div class="emz">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" height="150px">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add .imz {  overflow:hidden; }, This will prevent image from jumping outside.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated answer, you only need to add **`overflow:hidden`** and remove some extra styles

**HTML**

```
<div class="imz">
   <div class="emz">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" height="150px">
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
}
.imz {
  top: 50%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.emz {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.emz img {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;    /* Firefox */
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;      /* IE 9 */
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;     /* Opera */
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.emz:hover img {
 -webkit-transform:scale(1.05); /* Safari and Chrome */
 -moz-transform:scale(1.05);    /* Firefox */
 -ms-transform:scale(1.05);     /* IE 9 */
 -o-transform:scale(1.05);      /* Opera */
 transform:scale(1.05);
}
```